# Best strategy for deploying a package in production

Tags: sharepoint-online, deployment, continuous-integration

We are thinking in two different strategies:

1. Manual process. When a package (web part / extension) is fully
   tested and validated in the QA site collection, someone will
   manually add the package in the Prod App Catalog.
2. Automated process. An event, for example, a merge in the Master
   branch will trigger a build and a deploy in the Prod App Catalog. A
   merge in the Develop branch could, similarly build and deploy in the
   Staging App Catalog.

Which route do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

From this article, it seems Automated process is more suitable.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-deployments-what-you-need-to-know/m-p/15699

Comment: Thanks for sharing that